# Merge lines if starts with a whitespace with the previous line using regex and PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have to extract some data from a text file, but before that I need to concatenate a few lines using this rule: If the line starts with a whitespace then it should be merged with the previous line which doesn't start with a whitespace. Do this for all the consecutive lines which start with whitespace.

Although I have created the regex for that [which can be found here along with the sample](https://regex101.com/r/9rlsZK/1/), and the substitution panel shows the desired output, I am unable to incorporate it in the PowerShell script:

```
Get-ChildItem .\abc.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName
    #remove all lines starting with *
    $content | Select-String -Pattern "\*" -NotMatch |
        %{ $_ -replace '(\s+^\n?\s)', "" } |
        Set-Content $_.FullName 
}
```

I am unable to understand how I should make it work when the regex is working.

Comment: The `^` matches the start of the *string*. You need to pass the multiline option, like `'(?m)\s+^\n?\s'`. But you also need to make sure you are reading the whole file in, not line by line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For merging lines with the `-replace` operator you need the content of the file in a single string. On PowerShell v3 and newer you can achieve that by calling `Get-Content` with the parameter `-Raw`:

```
(Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw) -replace '\r?\n\s+' | Set-Content $_.FullName
```

On older PowerShell versions pipe the output of `Get-Content` through `Out-String`:

```
(Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String) -replace '\r?\n\s+' | Set-Content $_.FullName
```